# Ionic on Hold directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a div with collection repeat on which I apply an ng-class `ng-class="$index%2 == '0' ? 'blue' : 'yellow'"`,I also apply an ionic on-hold directive as`ng-class="{'selected': column.selected}"`?I want when the row is selected the red colour of selected class should get applied.The problem is if I write the second ng class first,red colour is applied but the first ng-class becomes invalid.Is there a way to achieve both of this

```
<div class="row brd rowclass" collection-repeat="column in tasklist_records track by $index" on-hold="onHoldFlag == true?'':onHold(column,$index)" ng-class="{'selected': column.selected}" ng-class="{white:$index%2 == 0,grey:$index%2 == 1,firstrow:$first}" item-height="50px" ng-click="goToAccountDetailScreen(column,$index)">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `ng-class` you can insert any Angular expression: why not using a **function** (defined on the scope) which analyzes the condition you want and returning a string containing the right class names (space delimited)?

Here is an example:

```js
angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic'])

.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
  console.log("MyCtrl");
  $scope.tasklist_records = [{
    id: 0,
    onHoldFlag: false
  }, {
    id: 1,
    onHoldFlag: false
  }, {
    id: 2,
    onHoldFlag: false,
    selected: true
  }, {
    id: 3,
    onHoldFlag: false
  }, {
    id: 4,
    onHoldFlag: false
  }, {
    id: 5,
    onHoldFlag: false
  }, {
    id: 6,
    onHoldFlag: false
  }];

  $scope.customClass = function(column, $index) {
    if (!column) return;
    var _class = "";
    if (column.id==0) _class += "firstrow ";
    if ($index % 2 == 0) _class += "grey ";
    if ($index % 2 == 1) _class += "white ";
    if (column.selected) _class += "selected ";
    console.log("customClass", column,_class);
    return _class;
  }
  
  $scope.onHold = function(column, $index) {
    console.log("onHold", column, $index);
    column.onHoldFlag = !column.onHoldFlag;
  }

  $scope.goToAccountDetailScreen = function(column, $index) {
    console.log("goToAccountDetailScreen", column, $index);
  }

});
```

```css
.selected {
  color: red;
}
.white {
  background-color:white;
}
.grey {
  background-color:grey;
}
.firstrow {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<html ng-app="ionicApp">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <title>Ionic List can swipe</title>
  <link href="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <ion-header-bar class="bar-positive">
    <h1 class="title">Ionic List</h1>
  </ion-header-bar>

  <ion-content>
    <ion-list>
      <div class="row brd rowclass" collection-repeat="column in tasklist_records track by $index" on-hold="onHoldFlag == true?'':onHold(column,$index)" ng-class="customClass(column, $index)" item-height="50px" ng-click="goToAccountDetailScreen(column,$index)">{{column.id}} - {{column.onHoldFlag}} - {{column.selected}}
      </div>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>

</body>

</html>
```